# Validating HMAC using SecurityServiceProvider with Silex

Tags: php, symfony, hmac, silex

I'm sending an hmac within the URL that I want to valid before allowing users access to the system.  There is no user database, so its simply validating the url parameters to verity it was generated by the correct server and users can't change those parameters to access other parts of the system.

I'm wondering if anyone has done something similar with the SecurityServiceProvider.  I can do this using the before middleware which is fired after routing and security firewall rules.  I'd like to stop this request at the firewall though if possible.

Comment: Possibly an answer to my question... http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-authentication-provider

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with silex's middleware function 'before'.  I'm sure this probably isn't the best way to go about this, but my app doesn't have users or authentication so I just need to check the key is correct and return the response.  If anyone has any comments on improving this I'd love to hear them.

When an external system is generating a url they must use the shared secret key defined in my config file, and accessible through $app['config']['hmac_key'].  the hmac is generated on everything after the hmac in the path.  so if ive got sub folders domain.com/folder/hmac/arg1/arg2/arg3.  The before filter splits the route at the hmac and builds the path after that.

```
// Before firing the controller check the hmac matches, otherwise return 403.
$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // 40 chars in a sha1 hmac hash
    if(!preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/i', $request->get('hmac')))
        $app->abort(403, "Invalid key.");

    // break the route down to the arguments used in hmac
    $route = explode('hmac_', $request->get('_route'));
    $route = explode('_',$route[1]);
    // build the path used to generate hmac
    $path = array();
    foreach($route as $r)
        if($v = $request->get($r))
            $path[] = $v;

    $path = implode('/', $path);

    // Generate hmac hash from path and key
    $hmac = hash_hmac("sha1", $path, $app['config']['hmac_key']);

    // If the hmac's don't match return 403
    if($hmac !== $request->get('hmac'))
        $app->abort(403, "Invalid key.");
});
```

Comment: When I am sending data, I usually generate the hmac using a collation of the URL params sent then compare the hash to ensure it was a trusted source. How are you ensuring that the data passed to you is trusted?

Comment: I am using the url params to generate the hash.  I'm hashing 'arg1/arg2/arg3' of domain.com/folder/hmac/arg1/arg2/arg3

Comment: I'm using silex's routing so the trusted source doesn't need to generate a url like arg1=blah&arg2=blah&arg3=blah (if thats what your talking about) its simply /blah/blah/blah.  There's really no difference hashing the two anyway as the key is substantially longer than the path.

Comment: yeah thats fine, I usually pass a timestamp as well so that the key has a limited lifespan.